# get data within a processing instruction tag in xml

Tags: java, xml, dom

here's my code  :

```
void validate(String fileLocation){
    try{
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(new File(fileLocation));
        String[] pageContent=new String[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < pageContent.length; i++) {
            String currentPageContent=  document.getElementsByTagName("?PG").item(i).getTextContent();
            System.out.println("the Current Page content is "+currentPageContent);
            pageContent[i]=currentPageContent;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

i have several tags as < ?PG 1 ?> , < ?PG 2 ?>,< ?PG 3 ?> denoting page numbers how can i get  get the data from page tag.

Comment: This doesn't look like valid XML to me - so you cannot process it with an XML parser.

Comment: do you know how to extract the value from a processing instruction tag?

Comment: Do you have an example XML fragment that illustrates how they are used? The code sample you have is somewhat unhelpful - there isn't enough information in the question to answer it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format and read XML processing instructions using Java StAX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404141/how-do-i-format-and-read-xml-processing-instructions-using-java-stax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use recursion to go over the your `xml` without messy nested `for` loops.
2. You can compare the Node type to be `PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE` and extract its contents.

Example xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<test>
  <ID>Test1</ID>
  <TestType name="abc">
     <AddressRange start="0x00000000" end="0x0018ffff" />
  </TestType >
  <TestType name="RAM">
     <AddressRange start="0x00400000" end="0x00407fff" />
  </TestType >
  <?PITarget PIContent?>
  <?PISource PISome?>
</test>
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException,
            SAXException, IOException {
        FileInputStream path = new FileInputStream("text.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(path);
        System.out.println();
        traverse(document.getDocumentElement());

    }

    public static void traverse(Node node) {
        NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
            Node currentNode = list.item(i);
            traverse(currentNode);

        }

        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE) {
            System.out.println("This -> " + node.getTextContent());
        }

    }
```

Gives,

```
This -> PIContent
This -> PISome
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read `Processing Instructions` in your code than you should do something like this:

```
        NodeList currentPageContent=  document.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < currentPageContent.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = currentPageContent.item(i);
            if(node.getNodeType()==Node.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE)
                System.out.println("the Current Page content is "+ node.getNodeType()+ " : " + node.getNodeName() + " : " + node.getTextContent());
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Processing instructions are exposed in the DOM(**D**ocument **O**bject **M**odel) as `Node.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE`.