# Space between processing instruction target and data is removed on copying element

Tags: java, xml, stax

**Background:** I'm splitting an XML document up into multiple parts using StAX, for example saving each paragraph separately. To do this I read the document using an `XMLEventReader` and iterate over the events. When I encounter an element I want to store I copy it to a `StringWriter` and persist the contents of the string.

However I'm hitting a problem when I encounter a processing instruction. I have replicated the problem with the following code:

```
package com.util.xml;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.junit.Test;

import javanet.staxutils.XMLStreamUtils;
import javanet.staxutils.io.StreamEventWriter;

public class XmlUtilTest {

    @Test
    public void xml_with_processing_instruction_is_retained() throws Exception {
        final XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        final String xml = "<p><?processing-instruction user=\"stuart\"?>Title</p>";
        final XMLEventReader eventReader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(IOUtils.toInputStream(xml));

        final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        while (eventReader.hasNext()) {
            final XMLEvent event = eventReader.peek();
            if (event.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
                XMLStreamUtils.copy(eventReader, new StreamEventWriter(stringWriter));
                break;
            } else {
                eventReader.nextEvent();
            }
        }

        final String output = stringWriter.toString();
        assertThat(output).isEqualTo(xml);
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be the same as the input (it's a simple copy), however the space between the processing instruction target (`processing-instruction`) and the data (`user=\"stuart\"`) is being removed:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<...ocessing-instruction[ ]user="stuart"?>Title...> but was:<...ocessing-instruction[]user="stuart"?>Title...>
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at com.util.xml.xmlcontent.ingestion.XmlUtilTest.xml_with_processing_instruction_is_retained(XmlUtilTest.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you show us an example of your xml and the criteria with which they are split?

Comment: It's not relevant to this question and I'm happy with the splitting process, the problem is the handling of processing instructions so I don't want to get side-tracked.

Answer (score 0):

The XML spec is pretty vague about exactly what the parser should report to the application in such cases. The grammar for processing instruction is

```
PI ::= '<?' PITarget (S (Char* - (Char* '?>' Char*)))? '?>'
```

and in most other cases "S" represents whitespace that's treated as ignorable, so a lot of people have assumed that the whitespace in a processing instruction is "ignorable" and therefore not to be reported to applications.

As pointed out here: [How do I format and read XML processing instructions using Java StAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404141/how-do-i-format-and-read-xml-processing-instructions-using-java-stax) the Stax specification is notoriously woolly about such details.